# How can I fix my script to run in proper order?

Tags: java, selection-sort

The program is supposed to return

> The test scores in descending order are: (Scores) The average is
>   (average)

The result that I am receiving is

> The average is (average) The test scores in descending order are:
>   (Scores)

How can I fix it to receive the proper return

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average
{
    private int[] data;
    private double mean;

    public Average()
    {
        data = new int[5];
        int number = 0;
        int Temp = 0;
        String[] Scores = new String[5];
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int index = 0; index < data.length; index++)
        {
            number++;
            System.out.print("Enter test score #" + number + ":");
            Temp = keyboard.nextInt();
            data[index] = Temp;
        }

        selectionSort();
        calculateMean();
    }

    public void selectionSort()
    {
        int n = data.length;

        for(int index = 0; index < n-1; index++)
        {
            int min_idx = index;
            for(int j = index+1; j < n; j++)
                if(data[j] >= data[min_idx])
                    min_idx = j;

            int temp = data[min_idx];
            data[min_idx] = data[index];
            data[index] = temp;
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String MyScore = "Your test scores in descending order are: " +     "\n";

        for(int index = 0; index < data.length; index++)
        {
            MyScore += data[index] + " ";
        }
        return MyScore;
    }

    public void calculateMean()
    {
        int Sum = 0;
        int Mean = 0;

        for(int index = 0; index < data.length; index++)
        {
            Sum += data[index];
        }
        Mean = Sum/data.length;
        System.out.println("The average is " + mean);
    }
}
```

What would I have to swap around in order to make this work?

Edit: The Average class is used in this file

```
public class AverageDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Average MyScores = new Average();
        System.out.print(MyScores);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post `main` (or wherever you use `Average` class).

Answer (score 1):

You should call `calculateMean()` only after calling `toString()`.
So you can either modify the constructor

```
selectionSort();
System.out.println(toString());
calculateMean();
```

or calling only `selectionSort();` in the constructor, then in your `main`

```
public class AverageDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Average myScores = new Average();
         System.out.print(myScores);
         myScores.calculateMean();
    }
}
```

By the way, you should use lowercase name for variables, this will fix the error in `calculateMean()`: you are calling `System.out.println("The average is " + mean);` but the variable is `Mean`.

Answer (score 0):

The error why it's not printing the correct average lies in this method:

```
public void calculateMean() {
    int Sum = 0;
    int Mean = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        Sum += data[index];
    }
    Mean = Sum / data.length;
    System.out.println("The average is " + mean);
}
```

You're printing out `mean` which is defined globally, but never initialized so it defaults to `0`. In this method you have the variable `Mean` (capitalized) which is the variable the actual value is stored in, that's the variable you want to print.

Comment: I changed it to Mean, it still gives me the wrong order of execution as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Average MyScores = new Average();
    System.out.print(MyScores);
}
```

When you create the `Average` instance the constructor is called. In the constructor there is a call to `calculateMean()`, which prints

> The average is (average)

When you print `MyScores` the override `toString()` is being called, which prints The test scores in descending order are: (Scores).

Take out the methods calls out of the constructor (they shouldn't be there in the first place) and call them from `main`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Average myScores = new Average();
    System.out.print(myScores);
    myScores.selectionSort();
    myScores.calculateMean();
}
```